# Customise Controls at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have controls on a form and I get its objects at runtime using assemblies. Now I want to change their properties at runtime like forecolor, backcolor and text.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type formtype = typeof(Form);
    foreach(Type type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
    {
        if (formtype.IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(type.Name);
            Form frm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            foreach (Control cntrl in frm.Controls)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(cntrl.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control cnt = (Control)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show(cnt.Name);
    cnt.ForeColor = colorDialog1.Color;
}
```

This code gets me the objects at runtime but when I try to change the forecolor it gives me an error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: i want to change the properties of control at runtime.

Comment: @Gapan Post here the error you get. Nobody can`t help you without knowing the problem.

Comment: it does not produce any error but does not change properties of control at run time...

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted have several problems:

1. `listBox1.Items.Add(cntrl.Name);` You are adding the control name not the control itself to the collection, and again `listBox1.Items.Add(type.Name);` added the form type name to the collection.
2. In the code:

   ```
   Form frm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   ```

   You are creating a new Form(s) instance(s) each time and you are not showing them anywhere.

So How to fix it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();

    Type formtype = typeof(Form);
    foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
    {
        if (formtype.IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            Form frm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            controls.Add(frm);//Add the new instance itself to the list
            foreach (Control cntrl in frm.Controls)
            {
                controls.Add(cntrl);
            }
            frm.Show();//show the new form created
        }
    }

    listBox1.DataSource = controls;
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";//or "Text"
}
```

**Edit:** Also make sure that `colorDialog1` is previously initialized and shown to get the  `colorDialog1.Color` value from it.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve here, but if you want to just get the current instance of the form that is running, you can use `Form.ActiveForm` for that....

Comment: if i use listBox1.Items.Add(cntrl); instead of listBox1.Items.Add(cntrl.Name); then i get output same as your code. my list box control does not get controls name. listbox is populated with controls but does not show their names. and in listbox's selected index change event it when i call messagebox.show(cnt.name); it show selected controls name but on cnt.foreclor = colordialog1.color; it does not change its color

Comment: of course the color will not change, you are creating a new instance of the form, not updating the instance that is already shown.., also to show the names of the items. you can use the data binding "I updated the answer to show you how".

Comment: i want to change the properties of selected control in list box control at run time is it possible?

Comment: of course! the code that I posted _will_ change the property of controls on the list box at run time without any problem.

Comment: Dear Jalal i implement your code but it does not work. Please can you explain me...

Comment: How `it can't work?`, what is the issue you have? or better of what really you are trying to accomplish? maybe there are a better solution to fix your problem.

Comment: dear when i try implement your code it does not produce error and also does not change the color.

Comment: This code _will_ create a **new forms** and change the back colors of  controls in the newely created forms from the main form that start them and contains the `listBox1`, I have test it myself.